# LibGDX: Can't seem to draw the objects in an array

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

**Enemy Class**

```
public class Enemy extends Sprite{

private Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(0,0);
private float speed = 30, gravity = 30 * 1.8f;


public Enemy(Sprite sprite){
    super(sprite);
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch){
    update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    super.draw(spriteBatch);
}

public void update(float delta) {

    velocity.y -= gravity * delta;
    setY(velocity.y + speed * delta);
}

}
```

**PlayScreen Class**

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private Player player;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private TiledMap map;
    private Rectangle rightRectangle, leftRectangle, playerRectangle;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderer.render();
        renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
        player.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());

        boolean wallLeft = leftRectangle.overlaps(player.rectangle);
        boolean wallRight = rightRectangle.overlaps(player.rectangle);

        if(wallLeft){
            System.out.println("wallLeft Overlap");
            player.velocity.x = 0;
        }
        else if(wallRight){
            System.out.println("wallRight Overlap");
            player.velocity.x = 0;
        }

        enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
        enemy = new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png"))));

        enemies.add(new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png"))));
        enemies.add(new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png"))));


        for(it = enemies.iterator(); it.hasNext();){

        enemy.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
        enemy.setOrigin(500, 500);

        }


        renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();

    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = width;
        camera.viewportHeight = height;
        camera.update();
    }
    @Override
    public void show() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        map = new TiledMap();
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

        player = new Player(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png")));
        rightRectangle = new Rectangle(1280,0,0,720);
        leftRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,720);

        player.setPosition(
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2f - player.getWidth()/2f,
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2f - player.getHeight()/2f 
                - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5f);
    }
}
```

So if I were to run this, the application would just freeze up and would not respond anymore. I believe the problem is when I try adding the 'Enemy' into the PlayScreen class. It ran fine before, when I didn't put the 'Enemy' class into the project. What I'm trying to do is, to draw each enemy within the array of enemies then set their position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing an `it.next()` in here to advance the loop.

```
for(it = enemies.iterator(); it.hasNext();){

    enemy.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
    enemy.setOrigin(500, 500);

 }
```

I think you dont want to be drawing the same `enemy` each time either, so you should set `enemy = it.next()` at the beginning of this loop

Also, Im not %100 sure on how the backend of this works, but I'm pretty sure you don't want to load up 3 copies of the same sprite in the following snippet. You should load the sprite once, and use the same one for each enemy

```
enemy = new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png"))));
enemies.add(new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png"))));
enemies.add(new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png"))));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is it possible to put both enemy = it.next() and it.next in the same for loop, cause when I do that, it gives me a NoSuchException error. Also, when I only put one of the enemy = it.next() or it.next(), it will always spawn my enemy at position (0,0). 

*I noticed that in the Enemy class, I set the velocity to (0,0), I removed that just now and it's still spawning at (0,0)

Comment: When using an iterator, the `it.next()` call returns the next enemy in the list (which you will need to be assigned to a variable, such as your `enemy` variable), and should only be called one time inside the loop since you only check `it.hasNext()` once a loop. If you aren't doing anything more than in the code above, a much more common and easier to understand way to loop over lists is like so:
`for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++){
  enemy = enemies.get(i); /* .. code here ... */
}`

Comment: Sorry, I cant comment on the rest because I haven't used Libgdx in a long time, but I recommend you work your way through some libgdx tutorials to try and help better organise and understand your code.

Comment: Also don't instantiate anything in your render method! This is called about 60 times a second and will then trigger lots of object creation. You are going to be triggering the garbage collector a lot. This could potentially hurt your game performance.

Do it in onCreate() instead.

Comment: Thanks for that, I don't have an onCreate method though. Is there another method I could use?